# KineticJS toDataURL() gives incorrect padding error in Python

Tags: python, kineticjs, decoding

I have a base64 string that I've acquired from KineticJS toDataURL(). It's a valid base64 string. This fiddle shows that it is: http://jsfiddle.net/FakRe/

**My Problem:** I'm sending this dataURI up to my server, decoding using python, and saving on the server. However, I'm getting a padding error. Here's my code:

```
def base64_to_file(self, image_data, image_name):

    extension = re.search('data\:image\/(\w+)\;', image_data)
    if extension:
        ext = extension.group(1)
        image_name = '{0}.{1}'.format(image_name, ext)
    else:
        # it's not in a format we understand
        return None

    image_data = image_data + '=' #fix incorrect padding
    image_path = os.path.join('/my/image/path/', image_name)
    image_file = open(image_path, 'w+')
    image_file.write(image_data.decode('base64'))
    image_file.close()
    return image_file
```

I can get around this padding error by doing this at the top of my function:

```
image_data = image_data + '=' #fixes incorrect padding
```

After I add the arbitrary padding, it decodes successfully and writes to the filesystem. However, whenever I try and view the image, it doesn't render, and gives me the 'broken image' icon. No 404, just a broken image. **What gives?** Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've already spent way too much time on this as it is.

**Steps to recreate (May be pedantic but I'll try and help)**

- Grab the base64 string from the JSFiddle
- Save it to a text file
- Open up the file in python, read in the data, save to variable
- Change '/path/to/my/image' in the function to anywhere on your machine
- Pass in your encoded text variable into the function with an name
- See the output

Again, any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Something else is wrong; I cannot reproduce your error. The data in the JSFiddle decodes as base 64 *directly*, without adding extra padding, and decode to a valid PNG image.

Comment: Check that your `image_data` string is not truncated; `len(image_data) == 223548` for me. `import hashlib; hashlib.md5(image_data).hexdigest() == '03918c3508fef1286af8784dc65f23ff'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you so much! I checked the length, and I was getting 223573, which I thought was extremely odd. Then I noticed the data:image/png;base64, substring in the base64 image data. I wasn't aware I was supposed to remove that, and once I did, it started working immediately. If you'd like to write up an answer for the reputation, that'd be fine, otherwise I can answer it myself.

Comment: Glad to have been of help; don't forget to award the bounty too, if you feel I deserve it! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add padding, you have the wrong string. *Do* make sure you are parsing the data URI correctly; the `data:image/png;base64,` section is metadata about the encoded value, only the part after the comma is the actual Base64 value.

The actual data portion is 223548 characters long:

```
>>> len(image_data)
223548
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(image_data).hexdigest()
'03918c3508fef1286af8784dc65f23ff'
```

If your URI still includes the `data:` prefix, do parse that out:

```
from urllib import unquote

if image_data.startswith('data:'):
    params, data = image_data.split(',', 1)
    params = params[5:] or 'text/plain;charset=US-ASCII'
    params = params.split(';')
    if not '=' in params[0] and '/' in params[0]:
        mimetype = params.pop(0)
    else:
        mimetype = 'text/plain'
    if 'base64' in params:
        # handle base64 parameters first
        data = data.decode('base64')
    for param in params:
        if param.startswith('charset='):
            # handle characterset parameter
            data = unquote(data).decode(param.split('=', 1)[-1])
```

This then lets you make some more informed decisions about what extension to use for image URLs, for example, as you now have the mimetype parsed out as well.